# Updating int value from Seekbar Java

Tags: java, android, integer

I've this Seekbar and an int defined outside the seekbar. The value of the int is the seekbar progress. All is fine, except that I want the value of the int to change as the progress of the seekbar changes. Right now, it gets the value from the seekbar only when the program is launched.

```
    int tableNumber = seekBar.getProgress();
    SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);

    seekBar.setMin(1);
    seekBar.setMax(20);
    seekBar.setProgress(10);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            Log.i("Number", Integer.toString(i));

        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: can you elaborate more? what do you want to achieve?

Comment: You have to update the int in the onProgressChanged of the seekbar

Comment: @snachmsm let's say i have a textView which displays the tableNumber value

Answer (score 2):

You have to update the `tableNumber` variable every time the seekbar progress changes.

```
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
        Log.i("Number", Integer.toString(i));
        tableNumber = i; // add this line 
    }
```

Comment: The answer above is right but make sure you make a different object of OnSeekBarChangeListener because for some use cases if the seekbar changes an API call and the on changing seekbar value you are hitting an API and updating the recycler view this causes an infinite loop of API calls so we need to add the listener object manually and remove also by passing null.


Like this
 ```mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(seekbarChangeListener)
 mySeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(null)```

If you need a detailed explanation comment here I will then write an answer for this.

Comment: i get the error `local variable tableNumber is accessed from within inner class; needs to be declared final` and when I declare it as final I get another error which says `<identifier> expected`

Comment: you have to declare `int tableNumber` as global variable, above all methods (not inside method in which you are initiating `SeekBar`). check out my answer

Answer (score 0):

declare `tableNumber` outside method and set its value in `onProgressChanged`

```
int tableNumber = 0; // declare above method

public void someInitiatingMethodMaybeOnCreate(){
    SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
    tableNumber = seekBar.getProgress(); // initial set

    seekBar.setMin(1);
    seekBar.setMax(20);
    seekBar.setProgress(10);
    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
            Log.i("Number", Integer.toString(i));
            tableNumber = i; // set current progress
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

        }
    });
}
```